Android App shows compatibility warning on Android 14 despite targetSdkVersion 34 and updated dependencies
I have an old Android app that I've upgraded. I've updated all the Gradle dependencies, set targetSdkVersion to 34, and made the necessary changes to ensure compatibility. However, when I install the app on a device running Android 14 (specifically the Galaxy S24 Ultra), it fails to install. On other devices running Android 14, I get a warning saying:
"This app isn't compatible with the latest version of Android. Please contact the developer for support."
Despite updating all the dependencies, Gradle version, and other configurations, I still see this warning during the installation process. I've thoroughly checked the project setup, including:
Updated targetSdkVersion to 34
Updated all Gradle dependencies and plugins
Migrated necessary code to handle any deprecated APIs
What could be causing this warning on Android 14, and how can I resolve it?
this is my grade:
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' // This applies the Crashlytics plugin

apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'

android {
    namespace 'arpamanagement.com.app.managementreports'
    compileSdk 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "arpamanagement.com.app.managementreports"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1040
        versionName 'arpa-7.2.54(alpha-5)'
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

//    lintOptions {
//        checkReleaseBuilds false
//    }
    lintOptions {
        // تبدیل همه خطاها به هشدار
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable true
        }
//        debug {
//            firebaseCrashlytics {
//                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
//            }
//        }
    }


    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src-gem"]
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // Firebase & Google Play Services
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:24.0.1' // یا آخرین نسخه

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.3.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:19.0.0"
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.5.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding4:rxbinding:4.0.0'


// Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // UI Libraries
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2"
    implementation 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'

    // Retrofit & OkHttp
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.12.0'

    // RxJava & RxAndroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.21'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.11.0'

    // Image & File Libraries
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.16.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.5.0'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'

    // Additional libraries
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:logger:2.2.0'
//    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper-compat:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre'
//    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    implementation 'ir.huri:JalaliCalendar:1.3.3'

    // ObjectBox
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectboxVersion"
    kapt "io.objectbox:objectbox-processor:$objectboxVersion"
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-kotlin:$objectboxVersion"

    // Custom Projects
    implementation project(path: ':lockscreen')
    implementation project(path: ':horizonalnumberpicker')
    implementation project(path: ':rahyab-hybrid-cpsdk-1.0.5')
    implementation project(path: ":searchablespinnerlibrary")
    implementation project(path: ":numberpicker")
    implementation project(path: ":longpresspopup")

    // New dependencies from the updated file
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.github.florent37:expansionpanel:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:4.0.0'

    // CameraX
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.4"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.4"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.4"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.4"

    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.8.6" // or the latest version
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    // This is optional and deprecated but might help
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.6"  // for ViewModel usage
    implementation 'com.github.AnwarSamir:FontAwesome:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.samanzamani:PersianDate:1.7.1'
    implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.3.1'
    implementation 'neshan-android-sdk:mobile-sdk:1.0.1'
    implementation 'neshan-android-sdk:services-sdk:1.0.0'
    implementation 'neshan-android-sdk:common-sdk:0.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:19.2.0' // or latest version


    // Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.20'
    ext.objectboxVersion = '4.0.2'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // Ensure this is uncommented if you're using JitPack
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectboxVersion"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // Ensure JitPack is included
        maven { url "https://maven.neshan.org/artifactory/public-maven" }

    }

    ext {
        myMinSdk = 23
        myTargetSdk = 34
        myCompileSdk = 34
        myBuildTools = '34.0.0'
        mySourceCompatibilityVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        myTargetCompatibilityVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
//        mySupportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
    }
}

apply from: "./dependencies.gradle"

ext {
    versionName = "1402.03.18"
    var = 'key0'
    var1 = '123456'
    var2 = '123456'
    var3 = var
    var4 = 'F:\\Project\\Android\\arpaKey\\arpaKey.jks'
    var5 = var
    var6 = var1
    var7 = var
    var8 = 'F:\\Project\\Android\\arpaKey\\arpaKey.jks'
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip


show your gradle

The error message when the installation via adb install fails on S24 would be helpful. BTW does the app contains native libs (.so files)? If yes which platforms beside armv7 are supported by your app?

I added my gradle to the question

the problem was related to this part
splits {
abi {
enable true
reset()
include 'armeabi-v7a'
universalApk false
}
}
I have added arm64-v8a to this part and the problem is solved.
